# How I can send over 1 Mb characters using Ajax to the Play Framework(2.1) Controller?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, playframework-2.1

I have Play Framework(2.1) Web application. I need to send large data info from the client side to Controller. For this purpose I use ajax:
**Client side :**

```
$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : '@routes.SomeController.saveInfo()',
data : {
myJson: "LargeData"
},
success : function(data) {
alert("Ok")
},
error: function() {
alert("Error!")
}
});
return false;
}
```

**Server side:**

**POST    /saveInfo                 controllers.SomeController.saveInfo()**

```
public static Result saveInfo() {

request().body().asFormUrlEncoded(); // NULL
request().body().asJson(); // NULL
request().body().asMultipartFormData(); // NULL
request().body().asText(); //NULL
request().body().asXml(); //NULL

return ok();

}
```

By that way I can send small portion of data but not large. Where is the mistake? Or How I can send large data from client to server side?

Comment: Is there any error message? Can you get any header instead of the body?

Comment: There is no any arror messages. A can't get header.

Comment: Did you try posting something without Ajax? Let's say a regular form with a huge text area? What happens?